# Auto-renaming of new Archetypes objects (Plone 4) stopped to work

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have a Plone 4 site which stopped to rename new Archetypes objects; after creation (as something like `/temp/portaltype.2015-04-23.1234567890`) and saving the first changes, including giving it a title, it should be renamed to something nicer (`/temp/an-object-with-a-meaningful-name`), but this doesn't happen anymore.

Perhaps the problem arose when I applied some changes to update Plone from 4.3.3 to 4.3.4 (to make one step at a time); but I have inherited a long `versions.cfg` which is solely sorted by package names and doesn't include any hints why certain versions were chosen ...

I'm able to go back two months and have a version which does the renaming, but without more knowledge about what to look for, it will be a very time-consuming process of re-applying every single change, rebuilding, starting and testing; but there have not been any changes to my schema definitions.  I have a `temp` browser which is involved in delivering the primary edit form. but this doesn't seem to be the case for the saving action.

Sadly I don't fully understand yet the mechanisms of the `base_edit` action which should - as far as I understand - call `Archetypes.BaseObject.processForm` and implicitly `._renameAfterCreation`, so I'd be grateful for some pointers how to debug this.  Thank you!

**Update:**
I have a few triggers in my product's `configure.zcml`, e.g.:

```
<subscriber
    for=".content.portaltype.PortalType
         Products.Archetypes.interfaces.IObjectInitializedEvent"
    handler=".events.onInitPortalType"/>
```

… with, in `events.py`:

```
def onInitPortalType(self, event):
    """
    Called after first edit of new objects?
    """
    print '/// onInitPortalType(%(self)r, %(event)r)' % locals()
    setInitialOwner(self, event)
    setStateToPrivate(self, event)
```

However, the event doesn't seem to be triggered, since I couldn't find the output in an `instance fg` session.

**Update 2:**
I noticed that `zope.event` had been pinned to a quite old version (`3.5.2`), so I'm trying to update to 4.3.4 more seriously now ([following this how-to](http://docs.plone.org/manage/upgrading/plone4_minor_upgrade.html)). This got me `zope.event` v4.0.3, but I have a version conflict now:

```
There is a version conflict.
We already have: zc.recipe.egg 1.3.2.
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section test.
  Initializing section test.
  Installing recipe zc.recipe.testrunner.
```

There seems to be a requirement for `zc.recipe.egg < 2dev` somewhere, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing significant changed between Plone 4.3.3 and 4.3.4 on Archetypes. Products.Archetypes changed from 1.9.7 to 1.9.8 and Products.ATContentTypes remains on the same version.

Pointers could be:

- There's a `_at_rename_after_creation` flag, which is `True` by default. This can be changed on the content type `class`.
- Is your type still activated in `portal_factory`tool? (Afaik this should have no impact on renaming after creation - but who knows :-))
- Any `Products.Archetypes.interfaces.IObjectInitializedEvent` subscriber?
- Issue I had once was, that the tmp id `portaltype.2015-04-23.1234567890` had the wrong format and AT did no recognise it as tmp id and therefore it did not rename it after creation. The method AT uses to check if the id is autogenerated --> https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/4.3.4/Products/CMFPlone/utils.py#L111 AFAIK the problem was, that the meta_type and portal_type was not the same anymore.

Comment: The Flag `_at_rename_after_creation` is explicitly set to `True`; the types are visible in the `@@types-controlpanel`; `isIDAutoGenerated` works ok (but is not called *after* submitting the form). There are some `IObjectInitializedEvent` subscribers, but not for the type currently inspected. Perhaps I should add an event function to trigger the renaming explicitly ...

Comment: I updated the question. The subscribed funktions seem not to be triggered (I tried `print` statements and `pdb.set_trace()`).

Comment: I guess you need to debug thru the whole stack. Try start in Products.Archetypes _renameAfterCreation method, if this is not going to be called, define the method in your custom type and add a break point. Then try setting a break point in _processForm.

Comment: The `Products.Archetypes.BaseObject` version of `_renameAfterCreation` was called on creation, but only *before* the form is rendered (not anymore... what the heck!); I copied it to the base class of my content classes, but this one is ignored.  As a workaround, I created an `auto-rename` action which can be triggered by the user; the persistent benefit is the possiblity to update the id after corrections of the title ...